# Textbox1.text from form1 to form2

Tags: c#, string, forms, textbox

I need help passing input in Form2.textbox1 to Form1.sti
Form1 = Main working window
Form2 = Popup window, to enter path.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string sti { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = sti;
        this.Close();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int CountR = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string sti { get; set; }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 popup = new Form2();
        popup.ShowDialog();
        popup.Dispose();
    }
   public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                
    Label7.Text = sti; 
     }
```

But it always returns Null.

I've builded it this way because I don't want user to mess with the path only IT administrators.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't shown any code *setting* `sti` (nor explained why you've given it such a cryptic and unconventional name).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by sttings of sti? Sti = Textbox1.text ? Textbox1.text = string? - "sti" translated from danish to english is "path"

Comment: you should do something like popup.sti = "stiring1"; in one line did you?;

Comment: Where you have set the value of "sti"?

Comment: Jailed abroad: textBox1.Text = sti;

Comment: you should set like : frm1.sti = "string1"

Comment: where did you set the sti value???????

Comment: @MikkelMellumHviid  what are you going to do?

Comment: Habib Zare - I dont really understand what you mean.
Mark Hall: I need a string(Textbot1 input) created in Form2 and delievered in Form1 and ready for use.

Comment: @MikkelMellumHviid: You've shown `textBox1.Text = sti;` within the code in your question, but not the other way round. **None of the code you've posted sets the value of `sti`**

Comment: @JonSkeet How do i set value of string from input textBox1.Text?

Comment: @ mikkel Mellum Hviid, dont mind but take rest and then answer the question 
"Where you have set the value of "sti"?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You are creating a new `Form1` that does not have a reference to the `Form2` that you created</strike>.

You changed your example, you have created 2 different sti properties, you need to assign the `Form2` sti value to the property in `Form1` before you close Form2.

This code should work for you.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string sti { get; set; } 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 popup = new Form2();
        popup.ShowDialog();
        sti  = popup.sti;
        popup.Close();
        popup.Dispose(); 

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = sti;
    }

}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string sti { get; set; } 

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sti = textBox1.Text;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

---

You can also create a static class that can be referenced from both forms, that way you are dealing with only one sti property. Something like this:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myProperties.sti = "Hello";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 popup = new Form2();
        popup.ShowDialog();
        popup.Dispose(); 

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = myProperties.sti;
    }
}

public static class myProperties
{
    public static string sti { get; set; } 
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = myProperties.sti;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myProperties.sti  = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your static class worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create another property on `Form2` which is used for catching a value from `Form1`

in `Form2`, add this: (*just like in form1*)

```
public string sti { get; set; }
```

so in your `Form1` code, it will look like this

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 popup = new Form2();
    popup.sti = sti;
}
```

and in `Form2`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = sti;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I tried with your edit's (sorry dont know the correct gramma :)), it didnt work. Still Null in sti

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data between form there is a good tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public String sti { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 frm = new Form3();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        sti = frm.sti;

        textBox1.Text = sti;
    }
}
```

other form:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{

    public String sti { get; set; }
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sti = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```